# Wrong mapping of Return key in Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, remapping

I have a problem with the mapping of the return key on a Fujitsu Siemens si2636 laptop. Though it is meant to be a standard return key it is mapped as a keypad return key. In Gnome or KDE this is not a problem but whenever I try to use xmonad, ratpoison or WMii where a lot of simple operations are done with `<super+Return>` I get nowhere as my return key returns the signal of a keypad return key.

I have tried remapping with xmodmap. I have tried to change the xmonad config file as to remap the "open new terminal" command to `<super+keypadreturn>` without success.

Is there a way I can remap the keys at boot-up before I load a window-manager?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the hal config file under `/usr/share/hal/fdi` so that it [maps your Enter key](http://hal.freedesktop.org/quirk/quirk-keymap-index.html) correctly.